# Google App Script: How to get GmailApp's permission?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I use

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
```

to send emails when there is a new form submission. The execution log is here

[image]

I searched and searched but still couldn't find where to turn on these scopes. My app script's project setting is like

[image]

There seems nowhere to add scopes.

**Update**:
I found the document and set my `application.json` file as below:
[image]
But I still got the same error message.

Comment: You can try adding the scopes in the error to you manifest file. appsscript.json but normally it will add it for you by just running a function from the script editor any function.

Comment: I just found it. Trying to find the syntax to put in the scopes.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: did you try to run a function from the script editor?

Comment: BTW you did not have to put all of the scopes on there

Comment: Actually I just tried, and it went through now.